# What is the time complexity of python dict has_key() method

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of python dict `has_key()` method?
Is it *O(1)* as in the case of the key in dict?

Comment: Yes, `O(1)`, but I'd just use `key in my_dict`.

Comment: Worst case it is *O(n)*. There have actually already been hackers that carefully constructed input to shut down a server because of that. But that only holds for very rare cases. Average case is *O(1)*.

Comment: has_key() was removed in Python 3.x.big-o is O(1)

Comment: Use 'if key in dct' or 'if key not in dct'

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'd like to read about that, do you have a link?

Comment: @timchap:here, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. I know has_key has been removed in 3.x, but we have lot of legacy code where we use has_key, want to make sure it's not a linear search and O(1) lookup for key in the hash

Comment: As @WillemVanOnsem hints it's `O(n)` in the degenerate case that every key collides, but then so is `in`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry, I meant the hack specifically

Comment: @timchap: it's already in `man python` under the `-R` flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** **worst case** it is ***O(n)***. But the **average case** time complexity is ***O(1)***. The **worst case is however *very* rare**.

When you do a lookup, the key is first double hashed (once by the type of the key and once by the dictionary). Based on that result, we know in which bucket we have to search, and we start searching.

It is however possible that *hash collissions* occur: in that case multiple keys are in the same bucket, so we have to search among multiple keys. Worst case all the keys are in the *same* bucket, and thus we fallback on linear search.

Hash collisions (with a large amount of keys) are however *very* rare. Usually it is safe to assume that - regardless of the size of the dictionary - the number of keys in the same bucket will be fixed.

The fact that it is *O(n)* had some interesting consequences on **security**. Say you have a server that stores and retrieves data in a dictionary. Then of course the response time will scale with such a lookup. Now a hacker can design input in such a way that all keys are placed in the *same* bucket(s). As a result lookup will slow down, and eventually the server will not respond in a reasonable time anymore. That's why Python has a flag [**`-R` for hash randomization**](http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html). This will change the hash function for every run and therefore make it harder for a hacker to design such input.

Comment: so, are the internal implementation or the runtime complexity of has_key,  key in dict and dict[key] are same

Comment: @PMat yes, precisely. Hash, then check the bucket. Check out [this][https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4Kc8xzcA68] video that goes over the internals of python `dict`s. It's outdated, but the ideas are still the same, basically.

Comment: @PMat: indeed. Only if you perform `d[key]`, you will return the value associated with key since a bucket contains tuples with keys and values.